# can you send an expression to a function in python or otherwise capture the text of the expression?

Tags: python, expression

Essentially - I'm making a slightly different test harness - and my requirement is simple, but I just have no idea whether it's possible in python?

all I want is to make a function check such that if i do

```py
    check( "check the total matches", 123, a + call_something() * call_something_else() )
```

I get output like:

```py
    check the total matches failed...
     expected:  123
    evaluated:  a + call_something() * call_something_else()
          got:  122
```

ie my question is about constructing that "evaluated" string.  In other languages I've sort of looked at the stack frame worked out where the source code for that function, searched for a matching assert line and parsed it - but it *feels* like there might be an easier way in python - because exeptions seem to contain that information?

Comment: No.  If you raise an exception, you can get a traceback that includes the calling line of code,  but the function itself has no clue what expression was used to create the values it got.

Comment: but a) that proves it is possible, and b) that gives a way of doing it - ie raise an exception, capture it, and parse the line of code - so I'll do that.... but the question then becomes "is there a better way" - because if it's possible for the traceback to find it - it means it's floating around in memory somewhere....

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Answer (score 0):

so this is ugly, but it's working for me:

```py
def show_expression( expression ):
    caller = [x.line for x in traceback.extract_stack(limit = 2)][0]
    return re.findall( r"show_expression\(\s*(.*?)\s*\)\s*$", caller)[0]
      
show_expression( 1 + 2 )
```